# Is there an easy conversion between sp and dp?

Tags: android, font-size

ALL,

I'm trying to implement a control described [here](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2012/07/06/how-to-add-a-notification-alert-badge-in-an-android-imageview/). I'm using Eclipse and it gives me a warning: "Should use "sp" instead of "dp" for text sizes".

I understand what is the difference between those 2, but now my question is: How do I modify that line in XML to get rid of the warning? Should I just change "dp" to "sp"? Or there is an approximation formula I can use?

I'm asking simply because right now I have only one Android device: LG phone and so don't know what will happen on other devices.

Thank you in advance for any help the community can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale factor of `sp` depends on the user's font size choice in the device's accessibility settings. On a stock Android 4.4 device, the setting is in Settings -> Accessibility -> Large text.

Turning that on magnifies all text specified in `sp` by the same factor. You can experiment with it on your device, or an emulator.

Without large text turned on, 1 dp == 1 sp.

Comment: So there is no easy way to convert to satisfy everybody ;-) OK, thank you for the reply.